# Flushing My DNS Cache - Windows 7?

Tags: cache, migration, domain-name-system

My hosting server migrated to another server today within its network. I have two websites on this service. "huevia"

When I pull them up in my browser they both still appear as a broken link.  I have cleared my DNS cache as per directions I found online.

Any other suggestions?

As well, I have an email address tied to one of these websites and this also still doesn't work after 24 hours.

Comment: Should have been migrated to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your hosting service didn't yack things up, it can take 24 - 48 hours for DNS to propagate the changes.

If you're close to the physical location of your site, say same city or state, you should see the changes in less than an hour (it can happen immediately as well). Is your domain registrar different from your hosting provider? If so, make sure you've got your DNS servers updated over at your domain registrar or your domain is pointing somewhere off in never-never land.

To flush your local DNS the command is simply "ipconfig /flushdns", but I can't (as of now) get to your website. Also, this question would probably make more sense to be on ServerFault as it's not programming related.

Comment: To follow up, where are you looking at the site from?  If it is your local crappy ISP in the US, they have a reputation for terrible DNS.  If refreshing your DNS **client-side** is not helping, you might want to try changing one of the DNS servers to manually configured to something like Google's DNS or OpenDNS on the computer you test from. If that is still an issue with different DNS servers, then you should complain to the hosting service.